# Ionic Setting Background Image For Page

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am fairly new to Ionic and I am trying to use a gradient image as my background on the `welcome page` of my application. I am able to load images on different pages of my app from the same `assets/imgs` folder, but not on the `welcome page`.  If I set the background to a plain color it works like a charm.  Any tips?

> Error Message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
page-welcome {
    #welcome{
        // background: color($colors, dark);
        background-image: url("assets/imgs/gradient.jpg");

        h1{
            font-size: 52px;
            margin-top:50px
        }
        .marginTop{
            margin-top:150px;
        }
        .logo{
            height: 100px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with a relative path:

```
background-image: url("../../assets/imgs/gradient.jpg");
```